# Setting format as percent in a cell using Google Sheets API

Tags: c#, .net, google-sheets-api

I'm trying to set a percent format when I create a cell, this is my code.

```
new Data.CellData
{
    UserEnteredValue = new Data.ExtendedValue
    {
        FormulaValue = "=(B2/C2)-1"
    },
    EffectiveFormat = new Data.CellFormat
    {
        NumberFormat = new Data.NumberFormat
        {
            Pattern = "00.0%",
            Type =  "NUMBER"
        }
    }
}
```

Current value shown is "-0.2488570834" and I need this "-24.88%". What I'm missing ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Try following the [Number format examples](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/formats#number_format_examples) provided in the document:
[image]

I've also found a [sample code](https://gist.github.com/raneath/1002621) to test this (converting format to your sample):

```
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var range = ss.getActiveRange();

  var rows = range.getNumRows();
  var cols = range.getNumColumns();
  for(var row = 1; row <= rows; row++) {
    for(var col = 1; col <= cols; col++) {
      var cell = range.getCell(row, col);
      var value = cell.getValue();
      if(typeof(value) == 'number') {
        cell.setNumberFormat("##.#%");
      }
    }
  }
```

Result:

[image]

The code sample is for Apps script but the implementation to C# would be the same. Change `Pattern = "00.0%",` to `Pattern = "##.#%",`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your help but in my case it didn't worked. I think my issue is more with the data structure I'm sending than with the string format.